# There is a classification of matrix representations of Euclidean group $\mathrm{E}(n)$ (also called $\mathrm{ISO}(n)$)?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra, group-representations

I'm wondering if someone has already done a classification of matrix representations of the [Euclidean group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_group) $\mathrm{E}(n)$, more specifically I'm trying to classify  $\mathrm{E}(2)$.

I watched a course on Lie groups and algebras, and the teacher had done a classification of $\mathrm{SO}(n)$. I'm trying to do something similar, and i reached a strange result (at least I didn't expect this): I found that the generators of $\mathfrak{e}(2)$ (the Lie algebra of $\mathrm{E}(2)$) are exactly sums of generators of $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$.
I don't know why, but I expect that more types of matrises could satisfy the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{e}(2)$.

If someone knows how to do that, I would appreciate to learn.